# Compare vector Numpy with Different Datetime object

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create "niv" (it's dataframe here ....but numpy vector 2D would suit me)... the loop is very slow.

```
  for d in range(1, 10000000):
            niv = cash[testmp.index[d] == cash.index.date]
.......
```

I would like use `np.where()`..

```
np.where((cash_np[0:,0:1]==testmp_np[0:,0:1]),cash_np,0)
```

but I can't compare.... because first column return not same object.

Example below for 'cash'.

```
cash_np=cash.reset_index().values
cash_np[0:1,0:1]

Out[]:array([[Timestamp('2012-02-21 08:01:00')]], dtype=object)
```

I would like use this... but doesn't work...

```
cash_np[0:1,0:1].date()
```

and for 'testmp':

```
testmp_np=testmp.reset_index().values
testmp_np[0:1,0:1]

Out[]:array([[datetime.date(2012, 2, 22)]], dtype=object)
```

I would like use this... but doesn't work...

```
cash_np[0:1,0:1].date()
```

yet this works

```
t = pd.Timestamp('2013-12-25 00:00:00')
t.date()
Out[]:datetime.date(2013, 12, 25)
```

I don't how to do.

Regards

SR70

Comment: Convert the index to datetime.date, then they will be the same type and comparable

Comment: it seems  that it is already a dateime.date.   type(cash.index) ....pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex

Comment: So what's the problem? Why can't you just do `testmp == cash.index.date`?

Comment: because I need a loop

Comment: Why do you need a loop?